# Floating Parallax DIV Background Image Jumps When Scrolled Over Embedded Vimeo YouTube or Flash in Chrome/Safari Only

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, safari, embed

I'm working on a parallax web template I downloaded that has divs with background images that parallax and float over other lower z-index content.

Whenever I embed a Vimeo or YouTube video using their iFrame code in the lower area, the background image that parallaxes will jump in the y-direction as soon as the floating div "touches" the embedded player.  The problem I believe has to do with Flash ultimately being embedded as an iFrame with a normal page embedded works as expected - feel free to try it.

This only happens in Chrome and Safari. Firefox and IE work as expected.  I've created a stripped down JSFiddle from my web template to illustrate the problem.  Try it out in the above browsers and you can see the issue happening - just scroll the result a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/wU2DU/2/

`Too much code - just see the JSFiddle - that's the easiest way to see the issue`

I really want to find a fix because I've designed my whole website already and just now noticed this problem in Chrome and Safari.

NOTE:  The problem isn't in the parallax JS code.  I left that in just so a sense of the effect can be seen.  The background image still pops without that code.

Comment: That's an interesting problem. It's clearly affecting the background-attachment property.

Comment: Id try to use the HTML5 video tag, with it effects like this can be avoided..

Comment: Try adding a Z-index to the iFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your embed code source has `wmode=opaque` inside it. Use this embed and it should work:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/60982085" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" wmode="transparent"></iframe>
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fxv76/

Comment: Was just revisiting this question, looks like the problem is fixed in all browsers now when I test my original JSFiddle. Will give this the answer check tho since your fix apparently worked when it was still broken in Chrome and Safari.